# Rails 2.3.11 RESTful route not calling create action from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a controller called "Notes", and its associated model is Note, with a text field called "note" (I know).

I have a very simple form in the new.html.erb view:

```
<% form_for(@note) do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.error_messages %>&nbsp;</p>
    <h2 class="productList"><label for="">Note: </label>
    <%= f.text_area :note, :cols => "50", :rows => "10" %></h2>
    <br />
    <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

However, upon clicking the "Submit" button, the action being called is from a completely different controller:

```
Processing OtherController#add_note (for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-30 09:04:42) [POST]
```

Please note that this action is not even defined in routes.rb, though the controller is set up as a resource.

My "notes" line in routes.rb looks like this:

```
map.resources :notes, :collection => { :note_list => :get, :get_json_list => :get }, :member => { :applications => :get, :replace => :get }
```

And "rake routes" yields these lines for the controller:

```
get_json_list_notes GET    /notes/get_json_list(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"get_json_list"}
note_list_notes     GET    /notes/note_list(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"note_list"}
notes               GET    /notes(.:format)  {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"index"}
                    POST   /notes(.:format)  {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"create"}
new_note            GET    /notes/new(.:format)  {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"new"}
edit_note           GET    /notes/:id/edit(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"edit"}
replace_note        GET    /notes/:id/replace(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"replace"}
applications_note   GET    /notes/:id/applications(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"applications"}
note                GET    /notes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"show"}
                    PUT    /notes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"update"}
                    DELETE /notes/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"notes", :action=>"destroy"}
```

I don't have anything bound to the form or controls in my Javascript either. What would make it call the wrong controller and action?

UPDATE - Here is the output of the form_for tag:

```
<form id="new_note" class="new_note" method="post" action="/notes">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <h2 class="productList">
    <label for="">Note: </label>
    <textarea id="note_text" rows="10" name="note_text" cols="50"></textarea>
  </h2>
  <br>
  <p>
    <input id="note_submit" type="submit" value="Create" name="commit">
  </p>
</form>
```

UPDATE 2 - Form is being passed "Note.new"

Comment: have you checked the output of form_for helper?

Comment: I have. It's just what you'd expect. Posting above.

Comment: Routes are processed from the top. Could you post full routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a freaking idiot. I have a Javascript listener bound to "note_submit" on another page.